# Trying to get property of non-object error while I should get back an object?

Tags: php, rest, postman

I am getting errors like: Trying to get property 'firstname' of non-object in D:\ShiroWorks\rest-api-authentication-example\api\create_user.php on line 24 when trying to post data with postman.

I tried using file_get_contents() function as array but I get the message "Unable to create user."

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/rest-api-authentication-example/");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");


include_once 'config/database.php';
include_once 'objects/user.php';


$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();


$user = new User($db);


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));


 $user->firstname = $data->firstname;
 $user->lastname = $data->lastname;
 $user->email = $data->email;
 $user->password = $data->password;



// create the user
if(
    !empty($user->firstname) &&
    !empty($user->email) &&
    !empty($user->password) &&
    $user->create()
){


    http_response_code(200);

    // display message: user was created
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "User was created."));
}

// message if unable to create user
else{


    http_response_code(400);

    // display message: unable to create user
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create user."));
}
?>
// The result of var_dump($data) is: 
array(4) {
  [
    "firstname"
  ]=>
  string(6) "Vilmos"
  [
    "lastname"
  ]=>
  string(5) "Szabó"
  [
    "email"
  ]=>
  string(15) "shiro@email.com"
  [
    "password"
  ]=>
  string(3) "555"
}
```

I should get back the "message": "User was created."

Comment: We will need the postman data to answer this question.  In postman when you are on the tab for this request, click on the code hyperlink (next to cookies and comments) below the send button.  Select CURL from the drop down and paste that code here as part of your question.  Your PHP code looks ok so I suspect that your request is malformed.

Comment: `json_decode` by default returns object, but your `var_dump` shows type as `array`. How it happened?)

Comment: Can you run `var_dump($user);` before comment `// create the user`?

Comment: ```
object(User)#3 (7) {
  [
    "conn": "User":private
  ]=>
  object(PDO)#2 (0) {}
  [
    "table_name": "User":private
  ]=>
  string(5) "users"
  [
    "id"
  ]=>
  NULL
  [
    "firstname"
  ]=>
  string(6) "Vilmos"
  [
    "lastname"
  ]=>
  string(6) "Szabó"
  [
    "email"
  ]=>
  string(15) "shiro@email.com"
  [
    "password"
  ]=>
  string(3) "555"
}
```

Comment: Postman data is too long so I will post it in two parts.
```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8888/api/create_user.php \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 119' \
  -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
  -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=97hhkrlai3apbcg3g2h9rcj5i7' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:8888' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: bbb45f60-9e7b-4b7d-989b-fe864a872eca,b0b9ffc7-4d75-4fa6-9e11-eee99d21f896' \
```

Comment: -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "firstname" : "Vilmos",
    "lastname" : "Szabó",
    "email" : "shiro@email.com",
    "password" : "555"
}'

Comment: `print_r($data);` and provide the output.

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [firstname
] => Vilmos
    [lastname
] => Szabó
    [email
] => shiro@email.com
    [password
] => 555
)

Comment: In your object, there is an extra space there. Is it a typo?

Comment: Looks like that postman is adding the trailing slash in the object keys. so, trim your keys and check does that work for you.

Comment: Trim doesn't work. Still unable to create user,

Answer (score 2):

The error was because of the database. One more row was set to NOT NULL and I didn't included it in the post request.

Comment: I found the same issue from the same tutorial and can confirm that the SQL fields 'created' and 'modified' require a default value of null when creating the database table. The error is thrown because the date fields are not included in the SQL statement to write the user to the users table. Simply setting the table date fields to allow a NULL value resolves the problem.